# Обращение к self.article не работает в Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть модель, которая при сохранении экземпляра вызывает функцию ip_constructor в методе save:

```
class IpConstructor(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = ip_constructor(self)
```

В функции ip_construсtor я могу оперировать self, например:

```
article = self.article
```

Но так же мне необходимо использовать функцию ip_constructor  в моем файле views.py. Запись там следующая:

```
class SpecAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        result = ip_constructor(self)
        return Response(result)
```

Но в таком случае запись:

```
article = self.article
```

Перестает работать и появляется исключение:

> Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  'dict' object has no
> attribute 'article'

Если использую такую запись:

```
article = self.request.data['article']
```

То функция работает корректно

Есть подозрения, что ошибка из-за отсутствия сериализации. Заранее премного благодарен!

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где обращения? Где записи? О каком save речь? Откуда по-вашему должен был взяться self.article? Где появляется ошибка? Что такое `ip_constructor` и что такое `Response`? Приведите [mcve] чтобы было понятно что вообще происходит

Comment: Я подкорректировал вопрос, буду признателен за Ваш комментарий

Comment: Когда вы пишете `result = ip_constructor(self)` внутри метода save, вы передаёте в функцию экземпляр класса `IpConstructor`. Когда вы пишете `result = ip_constructor(self)` внутри метода post, вы передаёте в функцию экземпляр класса `SpecAPIView`. Так как классы `IpConstructor` и `SpecAPIView` это очевидно разные классы, то вполне логично, что у них есть разные атрибуты, и нет никаких причин, почему вдруг `self.article` должен существовать в них обоих

Comment: Подскажите, это может быть из-за разных типов ?